# Traversing DOM Elements For GetComputedStyle.getPropertyValue Always Returns Null (Chrome Ext.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, getcomputedstyle

I'm developing a javascript function (used by a chrome extension) that would grab the largest text displayed (from font-size property) on a specific web-page.

It gets the content of the page specified through an ajax call and data that is returned by the call is transformed into the DomParser. Traversing the DOM, I get different Elements like:

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
[object HTMLUListElement]
[object HTMLLIElement]
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

Now I've written a function that gets the element style using `getComputedStyle`. The logic I've in it is:

```
 if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle)
 {
    strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(ele, null).getPropertyValue(cssProp);
 }
 //Where ele is the elements i got above (HTMLDIVElement e.g) and cssProp is 'font-size'
```

Function grabs around 460 different elements (test page) but **font-size is always null**. Can you please help setting this up?
`window.getComputedStyle` returns [object CSSStyleDeclaration] object for all the traversed elements.
`Document.getAttribute('attribute-name')` is working but that only gives the inline results and not the computed ones.
If there are other suggestion to achieve the same result, I'm open to them as well.

Thanks

Comment: What does this mean: `grab something like the highest text displayed (from font-size property)`? Are you trying to get the value of the element with the largest text shown on the screen?

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan Yeah!! Trying to fetch the largest text shown on a web-page.

Comment: Does DOMParser detaches the css styles associated with the HTML Element?